# Django two self-referential foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

A write simple application in Django 1.7. Is a model that represents the element of a linked list:

```
class TrainingUserWordSetItem(models.Model):
    training_set = models.ForeignKey(TrainingUserWordSet)
    user_word = models.ForeignKey(UserWord)
    prev_item = models.ForeignKey("TrainingUserWordSetItem", null=True, default=None)
    next_item = models.ForeignKey("TrainingUserWordSetItem", null=True, default=None)
```

When migrating I get an error:

```
hellodict.TrainingUserWordSetItem.next_item: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'TrainingUserWordSetItem.next_item' clashes with reverse accessor for 'TrainingUserWordSetItem.prev_item'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'TrainingUserWordSetItem.next_item' or 'TrainingUserWordSetItem.prev_item'.
hellodict.TrainingUserWordSetItem.prev_item: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'TrainingUserWordSetItem.prev_item' clashes with reverse accessor for 'TrainingUserWordSetItem.next_item'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'TrainingUserWordSetItem.prev_item' or 'TrainingUserWordSetItem.next_item'.
```

How make two self-referential foreign key fields?

**Update:**

Helped use related_name='+':

```
class TrainingUserWordSetItem(models.Model):
    training_set = models.ForeignKey(TrainingUserWordSet)
    user_word = models.ForeignKey(UserWord)
    prev_item = models.ForeignKey("TrainingUserWordSetItem", null=True, default=None)
    next_item = models.ForeignKey("TrainingUserWordSetItem", null=True, default=None, related_name='+')
```

Comment: I don't think it had been a good idea to close this question, the "duplicate" is a crap (and has few to do to this problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could actually probably accomplish what you're attempting with one field. I believe this would work:

```
next_item = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, default=None, related_name='prev_item')
```

Note the use of 'self'; according to the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey), `To create a recursive relationship – an object that has a many-to-one relationship with itself – use models.ForeignKey('self').`

Additionally, I would recommend trying this with a OneToOneField, rather than a ForeignKey, assuming that every item will only ever have one previous and one next item.

Comment: helped use: related_name='+'